# Wayland does not show popups

Tags: wayland

There are so many times when I want a popup to show and it does not because of "wayland"  I find that it is 3 steps backwards.

When I save a file, I should not get a message that a save popup dialog is somewhere.  It should just popup.
When i'm copying files and need to confirm replace .. Screenshots. There are so many examples where wayland does not act as it should but xorg does act as it should.

Is there any priority to fix this or is this the new way of Ubuntu?
I'm using ubuntu 23.04